A single word that encapsulates the "tense" emotional state and its positive counterpart
I am analyzing human emotions and based on my analysis goal, the valence of the emotion (i.e., positive or negative) is not very relevant. I am more interested in the arousal level of the emotion—for example, drowsy, calm, engaged, tense, panic, etc.
The word "tense" perfectly describes a distinct level of emotional state but I associate it more with a negative valence, such as anxiety or stress. I am curious to know if there is a word that encapsulates both "tense" and its positive counterpart at the same arousal level.
Example sentence: to keep women attracted during a relationship, one needs to sometimes increase their emotional state to a level higher than normal. It does not matter whether it makes them tense or excited but they have to be "insert word here".

If you refer to the action of focusing all one's attention, i.e. a mental effort, consider "concentration", even it's not really an emotional state.

Can you give more specific examples? What emotions, in what circumstances or with what details? Also there are slangy terms, some related to drug culture, that might work. Are you OK with that kind of thing or must it be formal New York Times quality language?

Surely panic is negative.

tranquil --> agitated

@Graffito the state that you are talking about is one level below the state that I am talking about. I would describe the state that you are talking about as "engaged". Tense is a level higher than that because one would not be uncomfortable when engaged but they would be uncomfortable when tense.

@StuartF I wrote stress and anxiety as examples in my question and I think it perfectly describes all situations that this state relates to for example, important deadline or public speaking etc that makes you slightly uncomfortable but not at the panic level

@TinfoilHat I did a quick search and it looks like agitated is pretty much a synonym for tense which means it does not really cover the positive counterpart

True in the emotion sense, but there is also sense 1 from the OED: “Originally: moved from a quiet or tranquil state, set in motion. Subsequently: moved backwards and forwards repeatedly; shaken, disturbed, stirred.”

@Alireza goad, perhaps?

There is only “not tense,” as many states can encompass the absence of being tense.
